# having an issue on contact form magento 2.4.0

Tags: contact-us

i am having a difficulties on contact form block, dont have themes, i use only the default luma on root/vendor/magento

Write Us

Jot us a note and we’ll get back to you as quickly as possible.
Name

please help
thanks

result:

Comment: Can you please add more details ? now sure what is the issue that you facing

Comment: thanks for your response here

http://www.clipular.com/posts/5313262919614464?k=NHLVEE9kkkNo7x8V9Bqpx9UOSH0

i used block script {{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}} on the contact page. but the result is this  http://www.clipular.com/posts/5313262919614464?k=NHLVEE9kkkNo7x8V9Bqpx9UOSH0 

dont have any template installed, i used the template on the root/vendor path

can you help me how to fix this issue?

thank you so much